# how to show results of data augmentation before and after keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation, data-generation

i am currently training a CNN with the ASL dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist.
 To optimize my accuracy I used the ImageDataGenerator from Keras. I wanted to print out the results of the Data Augmentation (image before and after the Data Augmentation). But I don't understand how to plot the results from datagen. This is my code:

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False, samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        zca_whitening=False, rotation_range=10,
        zoom_range=0.1, width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=False,
        vertical_flip=False)
datagen.fit(train_data)
result_data = datagen.flow(train_data, train_label, batch_size=128)
print(result_data)
```

train_data is a numpy array of shape (20, 28, 28, 1) and train_label(20, 1) as they are 20 images with 28*28 pixels and the third dimension for the usage in a CNN.
 I would like to plot it with matploit lib but also happy with anything else (np array of the pixels).
If someone could also tell me how I can print the amount of data the datagen generated would be awesome.
 Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can create default DataGenerator to plot original images easily

```
datagenOrj = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
```

You can flow a small sample like the first five images into your 'datagen'. This generator gets images randomly. To making a proper comparison, small and certain sampling can be good for large dataset.

```
result_data     = datagen.flow(train_data[0:5], train_label[0:5], batch_size=128)
result_data_orj = datagenOrj.flow(train_data[0:5], train_label[0:5], batch_size=128)
```

When you call the next() function, your data generator loads your first batch. The result should contain both train data and train label. You can access them by index.

```
def getSamplesFromDataGen(resultData):
    x = resultData.next() #fetch the first batch
    a = x[0] # train data
    b = x[1] # train label
    for i in range(0,5):
        plt.imshow(a[i])
        plt.title(b[i])
        plt.show()
```

Be carefull about plotting. You may need to rescale your data. If your data type is float, you need to scale it between 0 and 1 and if your data type integer, you should scale it between 0 and 255. To do it you can use rescale property.

```
datagenOrj = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)
```

I tried on my own dataset and it is working.

Best